# How to monitor users activities in my machine

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, users

I have a desktop PC with windons7 ultimate edition. I have created three accounts and a guest account is enabled in the machine.

I am the administrator and I want to monitor other accounts usage like which applications they are using, which files are created or modified or which websites they are surfing etc.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide quite a good tool for this. It is free and is called [Windows Family Safety](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/protecting-your-kids-with-family-safety).

There are a couple of restrictions: "Family Safety works best when every member of your family has their own Windows account and safety settings".

You can restrict access to applications and web sites and monitor how long people spend on an application. You can also control when people can login to the account.